# sorting 2d array with null values

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, null, multidimensional-array

Have tried to look for some other relevant examples, but couldn't find any to fix my problem. I have a 2d array. I need to put these in numerical order, but at the same time change the value in myArray[x][0] to the row it appears in

```
String[][] myArray = {
{"1", "john", "smith", "12345"}, 
{null, null, null, null}, 
{"3", "sam", "smith", "54321"},
{"5", "paul", "long", "15243"},
{"4", "simon", "short", "51423"}
};
```

should become

```
    {"1", "john", "smith", "12345"},  
    {"2", "sam", "smith", "54321"},
    {"3", "simon", "short", "51423"}
    {"4", "paul", "long", "15243"},
    {null, null, null, null}
```

I've tried using compareTo() but with the null value in getting some errors. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Show your code. Read the stack trace you get and try to understand it. Post it. then, if you're stuck, we can help you understand the error and fix it. We won't do your homework.

Answer (score 0):

Do a check to see if it's null with the boolean ==.

```
if(myArray[x][y] == null)
{
    //Move to end...
}
```

Comment: and then to change the values in the first column?

Comment: Use whatever swap method you are using already? It depends on how you are doing the rest of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see this, you can solve it by doing two passes.

1. First, you need to perform a more custom sorting which checks for null values.

   Have you tried using the `Arrays.sort` method? One of its overloaded variants allows the usage of a custom `Comparator`.

   You can probably implement a Comperator that does your complex sorting logic and also checks for `null` values.
2. Second, you need to iterate through your sorted array and modify the first value in each row.

   ```
   int index = 1;
   for (String[] row : myArray) {
       if (row[0] != null) {
           row[0] = String.valueOf(index);
       }
       index++;
   }
   ```